# Why copy on Element make lxml.html.tostring returns escaped characters

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

Like following:

```
In [1]: from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

In [2]: import copy

In [3]: node = fromstring('<div>asdf\r\nasdf</div>')

In [4]: tostring(node, encoding='unicode')
Out[4]: '<div>asdf\r\nasdf</div>'

In [5]: tostring(copy.deepcopy(node), encoding='unicode')
Out[5]: '<div>asdf&#13;\nasdf</div>'
```

Actually there is `from html import unescape` to solve the problem.
Is there a better way to use both `copy` and `tostring`?

Comment: You don't need `html.unescape` for this. `&#13;` is a perfectly fine and valid HTML encoding for `\r`. Try this: `fromstring('<div>asdf&#13;\nasdf</div>').text` – you'll see, the `\r` is back.

Comment: Or why do you care whether the CR character is printed literally or with an entity? They both mean the same in HTML. When the snippet is rendered (in a browser etc.), the whole `\r\n` sequence is displayed like a space in either case.

Comment: @lenz The problem becomes awful when we use `import lxml.html.builder as E` to build html, e.g. `node = E.HTML(E.BODY(E.DIV("随便乱写")))`. `print(tostring(copy.deepcopy(node), encoding='unicode'))` outputs `<html><body><div>&#x968F;&#x4FBF;&#x4E71;&#x5199;</div></body></html>`, which is difficult to read.

Comment: I don't see what the `builder` has to do with this, I thought the `deepcopy` was causing the escapes.

Comment: In any case, HTML wasn't designed for reading from source, so if you decide you want to parse it with your eye instead of using a machine, then you'll probably have to find some ugly work-around. Prettifying the result isn't a top priority in the `lxml` library in my experience.

Comment: Maybe you can replace the deepcopy using `tostring` and `fromstring`. That way you can control how non-ASCII characters are serialised. Maybe this is even what `copy.deepcopy` does under the hood.